# Function declaration error when compiling with Kotlin 12

Tags: kotlin

I've inherited an older Kotlin codebase, and attempting to compile with the newest compiler had many issues. The one that I'm having trouble figuring out are these strange functions that are hanging out in the middle of a class, without any apparent call. I'm wondering if anyone knows what this used to be, and what it was replaced with in newer versions of Kotlin?

```
public class SomeAdapter(val friends: SomeAdapterProvider, val listener: OnItemClickedListener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<SomeAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    trait OnItemClickedListener {
        fun onItemClicked(f: Friendship)
    }

    private inner class ViewHolder(v: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v), View.OnClickListener {
        override fun onClick(v: View) {
            listener.onItemClicked(somethings[getPosition()])
        }

        val text: TextView by inject(android.R.id.text1)
        val image: Picture by inject(R.id.imageview);

        {
            itemView setOnClickListener this
        }
    }

    {
        setHasStableIds(true)
    }
}
```

Specifically, the lines in question are the `itemView setOnClickListener this` and `setHasStableIds(true)` , both in-between braces just hanging out.

Comment: Here's the fixed version of your code (as @D3xter suggested below): https://gist.github.com/abreslav/176c69cd809d79e96c71

Comment: The fixed version should be an answer, without an outside link where content could vanish or move.  I added it below for reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prefix those 2 function blocks with "init",
see [Prefixes For Initializer Blocks](http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/03/kotlin-m11-is-out/)

Comment: Great, thank you very much for the fix and the reference to the change!

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @Andrey in his comment to the question, and along with the answer from @D3xter (adding `init` to the [initialization blocks](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors)), here is the updated code (for reference):

```
public class SomeAdapter(val friends: SomeAdapterProvider, val listener: OnItemClickedListener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<SomeAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    trait OnItemClickedListener {
        fun onItemClicked(f: Friendship)
    }

    private inner class ViewHolder(v: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v), View.OnClickListener {
        override fun onClick(v: View) {
            listener.onItemClicked(somethings[getPosition()])
        }

        val text: TextView by inject(android.R.id.text1)
        val image: Picture by inject(R.id.imageview);

        init { // FIXED here
            itemView setOnClickListener this
        }
    }

    init { // FIXED here
        setHasStableIds(true)
    }
}
```